# Move image left to right continuously

Tags: ios, animation, nstimer

I need to make run this animation from left to right continuously. Now Is working, but show 1 time only (when the game is loaded). I want to make this animation run continously, left to right continuously. Timer and speed is already working. Here my current code:

```
- (void)airplane1Code {
    airplane1.center = CGPointMake(airplane1.center.x + 10, airplane1.center.y);
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a UIView animation with the UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat

```
airplane1.center = CGPointMake(startX, startY);
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 //10seconds
                      delay: 0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     airplane1.center = CGPointMake(endX, endY);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

That will make it do the same animation from start to end over and over. In order to stop the animation, call

```
[airplane1.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: I think we are close, but this code doesn't work. I receive a error "No know class method for selector' animateWithDuration: delay: option::"

Comment: Ah, my bad - it was a typo. I read it off the screen on another machine. add a `completion:^{ }` parameter to the end of the animation message. I fixed the sample in my answer, but used nil for the completion since you're going to leave it running indefinitely. Xcode will autocomplete if you start typing "completion" before the right bracket.

Comment: No Luck, here my current code:    airplane1.center = CGPointMake(+200,50);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 //10seconds
                        delay: 0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                        animations:^{
                        airplane1.center = CGPointMake(+330,80);
              }
            completion:nil];

Comment: What's wrong with it? I did a copy/paste of your code in -viewDidAppear: and it's working fine. Animations can get wonky if you try starting the them in -viewWillAppear, so do the initial positioning in -viewDidLoad or -viewWillAppear and start the animation in -viewDidAppear

Comment: @HEMAN85 This answer is correct, as  Abhi Beckert confirms. Can you please mark it as accepted since I/we took the time to help you out? Thanks!

Comment: A found my own solution for this, I can't mark your post as accepted because you don't  solve my issue. Sorry

Comment: This code solve my issue: -(void) airplane1Code{
    
    // airplane1 Moving Speed / Left to Right Position
    
    airplane1.center = CGPointMake(airplane1.center.x +15, airplane1.center.y);
    if (airplane1.center.x > 375){
    
    ramdomPosition = arc4random() %1;
    ramdomPosition = ramdomPosition -1;
    
    airplane1.center = CGPointMake(ramdomPosition, +55);
    
    // Time to Show airplane1 Again in x Seconds
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:25.0]];

Comment: What exactly were you looking for? If you needed specific details answered, you should say so in the original question. Keep that in mind for next time because good questions beget good answers and it benefits the whole community.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the airplane to show up on the start side after it disappears from the end side, just reset the center off screen on the start side once it passes the window's frame. If you want another plane to show up and start flying after that one has left, then add another plane object and move them at the same time.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    -(void) airplane1Code{
        airplane1.center = CGPointMake(airplane1.center.x + 10, airplane1.center.y);
        if(airplane1.center > screenWidth + halfTheImageSize)
           // if the plane is completely off the screen, move the image to other side
           // and keep running this method with your loop
           airplane1.center = CGPointMake(0 - halfTheImageSize, airplane1.center.y);
    }
```

Comment: @HEMAN85 the correct approach is what Cameron suggested. But you might want a different animation (perhaps something with keyframes to move backwards and forwards in a loop for example). Look up the documentation for the method in Cameron's answer to learn how it works.